# translate the pseudocode into MIPS assembly language

Tags: assembly, mips, translate

1). `for ( t0 = ´A´; t0 <= ´Z´; t0++) Mem[a0++] = t0;`

2). `t0 = 2147483647 - 2147483648;`

for the first one, I am kind of confuse how to translate `Mem[a0++]`,
I am a beginner of MIPS, for the second, I can't find out the key point,just think it can't be that simple,

anyone can explain please?

one more question, what the different between mult and multu, can I get an example please?

Comment: Question 1 can't be properly answered since you haven't specified if you want to store all of `$t0`, or just the least significant byte or half-word.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
addi $t8 $zero 'Z'
addi $t0 $zero 'A'
loop: 
    sw   $t0 0($a0)
    addi $a0 $a0 1
    addi $t0 $t0 1
    ble  $t0 $t8 loop
```

2.

`addi $t0 $zero -1`

Comment: First store at $a0 then increment $a0